# Advice for setting up a static file server with ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, static-content

I would like to set up a subdomain (similar to stackoverflow's http://sstatic.net/) in order to serve static content for my existing web applications. I have never done this before and was wondering if anyone has advice - which technology to use (i am using the Microsoft stack), how i should structure the static site, what are the security and caching considerations etc.

ANY advice would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not to state the obvious, but if it's truly static, why do you need ASP.NET?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539748/what-is-the-best-way-to-optimize-a-windows-server-2008-box-running-iis7-to-serve) has some advice on optimizing IIS as a static file server.  If people do need to be authenticated to view static content, that will obviously complicate it slightly.  sstatic.net does not use authentication.

Comment: Matthew, you raise an excellent point to which i do not have a real retort. My initial goal with doing so in ASP.NET was to create a versionable set of files that can be packaged in a solution and stored in a version control system. I'd planned to package the files in a ASP.NET project and keep it in the same solution as the web site that will access said files, making development a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out Amazon's [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) services. Both are low cost and high performance. Their focus is serving up content.

I'm a happy S3 customer.

Added: You can easily set their services up so they appear as a subdomain of your site. Eg assets.yourdomain.com

Comment: Same here - S3. been doing this for ages. Awesome service and price point.